# Estimation of speed from log/Lat co-ordinates?

Tags: gps, standard-error

I have some vehicle based *GNSS* data. The data is *GNSS* time to a precision of *1* second and the corresponding lat and long coordinates in decimal degrees.
The data sampling was inconsistent, ie not always *1hz*.

I know how to establish the mean estimate for the vehicle speed by doing *Δs/Δt*.

If I were to continue on the basis that

- the time is correct and
- the Standard Dev in the Postional accuracy was *5* metres

How do I establish the uncertinity in the speed estimate by way of error propagation/some other method? The aim is to create a speed time graph to a confidence of *95% (2 SD)*.

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to simply +/- the resultant *Δs* by *5* metres.  However, as the speed is low at some point this can generate negative values.  I don't know how to incorporate an uncertinty in the lat/long cordinates, which I am assuming is a better than method than applying the uncertinity to the calculated distance

Comment: Xheck Wikipedia for "degree of latitude" and "degree of longitude": you get the formula for Earth, and so you can transform dLat and dLong into km (very precisely) and pytagoras theorem gives you distance. But so you can check with worst case (no need of complex geometry: now you are in Cartesian, so all calculation are obvious for error. Note: differential GPS works knowing that within a minute or so (and within 30 km or so) the errors between measures should be the same (magnitude and direction): note GPS will not deliver good precision anyway (std NMEA has fix number of digits)

Comment: bit late, but lots of GPS devices will report speed as part of their NMEA output.  this can be quite a good estimate as I believe the device will be using this internally to help itself maintain a better position fix

Answer (score 0):

If you assume a constant error in position, the faster the vehicle is traveling, the lower the percentage error will be.

Here is the problem, if you assume a +/- 5m error in positioning, your worst case scenario is a 10m difference between positions in one second for a stationary vehicle.  That equates to a 10m/s speed, which is equivalent to 22mph, for a vehicle that is not even moving. I don't think you can assume 95% accuracy in speed estimation until the vehicle is reporting a speed of at least 90 m/s.

Comment: Note: your worst scenario is an non-realistic one. Relative position between two GPS fixes (nearly at same time) has much better precision. Very high precision GPS setups (differential GPS, etc.) require such assumptions (and I can tell you: it works very well).

Comment: I know. Are you using a system with real-time correction?